# Que problema puedo llegar a tener si genero un campo autonumerico, pero buscando al mayor Id y sumandole 1?

Tags: mysql, c#, sql, sql-server, mysqli

Se me ocurrió esta pregunta practicando en SQL, y vi que hay varias formas de generar un campo autonumérico, por ejemplo usando Identity, pero si recupero el ultimo valor y le sumo 1 (con esta consulta: SELECT MAX(Id) + 1 FROM [Nombre de la tabla]) me puede llegar a generar un problema?

Y si estoy usando la consulta ya mencionada, tengo datos cargados, y quiero cambiar a Identity, puedo llegar a tener algún problema?

Que pasa si al recuperar un valor, le sumo 1 e inserto el nuevo dato con ese valor?

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes tener un problema de concurrencia si dos personas hacen el proceso al mismo tiempo y por lo tanto obtendrían el mismo valor.

Por eso es importante utilizar las herramientas que se tienen disponibles para generar secuencias o autonuméricos (al mencionar identity, parece que usas SQL Server y no MySQL).